# Is there any way to read data offline without setPersistance(true) with firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I want to read data offline for my users, but Persistance mode will make OnDataChange in ValueEventListener call twice. how can I prevent it. I need to use ValueEvent for my own purpose. someone help me please.

Update : I am making a friend suggestions list for users in my app, the suggested user must dont have any relationship with the current user. and this is my code ( I use Persistance for offline data as Firebase's suggestion)

```
 valueEventListener_check_relationship=new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot_root) {

            num_fiend_req=0;
            num_sent_req=0;
            update_badges(num_sent_req,tv_badges_sent_req);
            update_badges(num_fiend_req,tv_badges_friend_req);
            arrayList_suggestions.clear();
            adapter_suggestions.notifyDataSetChanged();

            GlobalConstants.ROOT_REF.child(GlobalConstants.CHILD_USERS)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                                Object_User user_suggested=snapshot.getValue(Object_User.class);

                                if(!user_suggested.user_id.equals(GlobalConstants.getMyUID())){

                                    if(!dataSnapshot_root.hasChild(user_suggested.user_id))

                                        addToList(user_suggested);


                                    else {
                                        RemoveUserFromlist(user_suggested);

                                        if (dataSnapshot_root.child(user_suggested.user_id)
                                                .hasChild(GlobalConstants.CHILD_REQUESTING)){
                                            String values=dataSnapshot_root.child(user_suggested.user_id)
                                                    .child(GlobalConstants.CHILD_REQUESTING)
                                                    .getValue().toString();

                                            if (values.equalsIgnoreCase(GlobalConstants.VALUE_REQUESTING_SENDER))
                                                num_sent_req++;
                                            else num_fiend_req++;

                                        }
                                        update_badges(num_sent_req,tv_badges_sent_req);
                                        update_badges(num_fiend_req,tv_badges_friend_req);
                                        adapter_suggestions.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }


                            }



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    GlobalConstants.ROOT_REF.child(GlobalConstants.CHILD_RELATIONSHIP)
            .child(GlobalConstants.getMyUID()).keepSynced(true);

    GlobalConstants.ROOT_REF.child(GlobalConstants.CHILD_RELATIONSHIP)
            .child(GlobalConstants.getMyUID())
            .addValueEventListener(valueEventListener_check_relationship);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain why it's a problem for your listener to be invoked twice.  What are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Please add the code that provides this behaviour and please also responde with @

Comment: why are you checking the relationship offline? It cannot be guaranteed that the data has not changed while being offline?

Comment: that is the problem, we can not check if we are offline, the data will be wrong. you should read the question carefully. It is not just about check data. check data only if we are online, my friend.  thanks for your response

Comment: this problem will happen even we are online. I dont know why.