# Firebase setPersistence (true) make wrong logic

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a chat app, I use setPersistence to read data offline. this is the problem. I have 2 users, A and B example.

- B Locks A when B is offline first ( of course, it is not success )
- Then A Locks B when A is online ( success )
- But when B is reconnected, B Locks A now ( A become be blocked )
- How can I prevent this kind of wrong logic?

And one more thing. this is [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176646/is-there-any-way-to-read-data-offline-without-setpersistancetrue-with-firebase?noredirect=1#comment97095929_55176646) with setPersistence too, please help me. thanks

update : I sent an email to firebase team and they suggested 2 options. Tthe first one is turn off the Persistence mode ( ofcourse we cannot read data offline so this is not the approach we can consider ), and the second one is write log for every single event that user made with timestamp ( I dont know how to do this, it is quite complex )

Comment: Check user status is successfully changed for both users in DB every time?

Comment: I have check relationship everytime before I update the new data. I have set .addOnSuccess and .addOnComplete too, but it dose not works

Comment: Sorry fot that,  but this is not about the code, sir. just about the setPersistence's Request Queue when user offline and when they are reconnected, the logic will be wrong. could you help me with this problem Frank ? thanks